# Rule to send mail when device (thing) is disconnected from AWS IoT

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, iot, rule-engine

I am working on an IoT based project, where I get data from raspberryPi and send it to AWS IoT cloud.

I have created a couple of rules to save data in DynamoDB and send emails on certain conditions. But I am struggling with **how to send an email if the device gets DISCONNECTED**.

Basically I was wondering if there is any way to get the **eventType: disconnected**
Screenshot and perform an action upon this event.

[image]

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, basically you have to create a rule that gets executed when the **disconnected**  lifecycle event is triggered. 
[In my case its like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vNru.png)

For more reference you can follow this link: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a rule that periodically attempts to connect with your device and, in the instance of a failure, sends you an email. Your device is not going to send a message as it disconnects because that would require it to know in advance that it was going to disconnect.

Pseudo code:

```
Run every x amount of time:
    if connectionTest == false
        sendEmail()
```

To clarify - **you will not get an event type "disconnected" because if your device is disconnected it will not be able to return an event object.** You will instead get an error which you will have to catch.

Comment: @user7366236 Apologies, I had not read your answer. It does make sense that AWS would keep track of connections / disconnections. I'm glad you found a better solution than the one I suggested.